# Is it possible to use || in PHP switch?

Tags: php, switch-statement, fall-through

```
switch ($foo)
    {
        case 3 || 5:
           bar();
        break;

        case 2:
          apple();
        break;
    }
```

In the above code, is the first switch statement valid? I want it to call the function `bar()` if the value of `$foo` is either 3 or 5

Comment: I don't know a lot about PHP but I would assume (3 || 5) to translate to TRUE.

Comment: `3 || 5` seems to get evaluated to just `true` inside a switch statement and thus will always call `bar()` for any value of `$foo`.

Comment: @Mark Rushakoff - No, a loose comparison between the switch value and the case value is made, and if, e.g., $foo == 0 then the 3 || 5 case code will not be executed. (Just like if (0 == (3 || 5)) would resolve to false.)

Comment: @GZipp: Oops, you're right.  I didn't catch that when I tried running the code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should take advantage of the fall through of switch statements:

```
switch ($foo)
    {
        case 3:
        case 5:
           bar();
        break;

        case 2:
          apple();
        break;
    }
```

The [PHP man page](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) has some examples just like this.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you need is:

```
switch ($foo)
{
    case 3:
    case 5:
       bar();
    break;

    case 2:
      apple();
    break;
}
```

Interestingly, I've heard that Perl is (or maybe even has, by now) introducing this syntax, something along the lines of:

```
if ($a == 3 || 5)
```

I'm not a *big* fan of that syntax since I've had to write lexical parsers quite a bit and believe languages should be as unambiguous as possible. But then, Perl has solved all these sorts of problems before with those hideous tail-side `if`s and `or`s so I suspect there'll be no trouble with it :-)

Answer (score 5):

Instead, use one of the primary advantages of `switch` statements:

```
switch($foo) {
    case 3:
    case 5:
        bar();
        break;

    case 2:
        apple();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I think what you've got there is equivalent to:

```
    <?php

    $foo = 5000 ;

    switch( $foo )
    {
      case true :   // Gzipp:  an '=='-style comparison is made
        echo 'first one' ; // between $foo and the value in the case
        break;             // so for values of $foo that are "truthy"
                           // you get this one all the time.

      case 2:
        echo 'second one';
        break;

      default:
        echo 'neither' ;
        break;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: The `case true:` line will _not_ always be gotten. Each case value is loosely compared to the switch value; if it resolves to true the code is executed. So, if $foo is 0, or '', or anything else that loosely resolves to false, the case will be bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you wrote `case 3 || 5:`, then you might as well just write `case True:`, which is certainly not what you wanted. You can however put case statements directly underneath each other:

```
switch ($foo)
    {
        case 3:
        case 5:
           bar();
        break;

        case 2:
          apple();
        break;
    }
```